# Dear sirs I can't get OrderStateMachine to generate the MSSQL database schema

Tags: entity-framework-core, masstransit

I'm using Masstransit for the first time, and can't make my sag's Persistable. Following the documented saga sample (EF Core): https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/efcore.html

Generating the Initial migration fails, being quite new to both EF and masstransit I'm lost.
Looks like DI can't find the correct DbContextOptions

PM> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -c OrderStateDbContext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'OrderStateDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

- MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCore v7.1.7
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v5.0.4
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design v5.0.4

Code;

```
collection.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderStateMachine, OrderState>()
                    .EntityFrameworkRepository(r =>
                    {
                        r.ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Pessimistic; // or use Optimistic, which requires RowVersion

                        r.AddDbContext<DbContext, OrderStateDbContext>((provider, builder) =>
                        {
                            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, m =>
                            {
                                m.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
                                m.MigrationsHistoryTable($"__{nameof(OrderStateDbContext)}");
                            });
                        });
                    });


 public class OrderStateDbContext :
        SagaDbContext
    {
        public OrderStateDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<ISagaClassMap> Configurations
        {
            get { yield return new OrderStateMap(); }
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any help

Duncan

Answer (score 0):

First, you are reading the old v6 documentation (which was preserved for those on v6). You should be referencing the [current documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/).

Second, I don't see any issue with the two types, the context should be available in the assembly. For a working example, look at [ForkJoint](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ForkJoint/blob/master/src/ForkJoint.Api/Startup.cs).

It registers the DbContext separately and uses that DbContext in the saga repository, but it should work either way.